# Scikitlearn grid search random forest using oob as metric?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, metric, grid-search

Have looked at data on oob but would like to use it as a metric in a grid search on a Random Forest classifier (multiclass) but doesn't seem to be a recognised scorer for the scoring parameter. I do have OoB set to `True` in the classifier.
Currently using `scoring ='accuracy'` but would like to change to oob score.
Ideas or comments welcome

Comment: See also https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/66238/55122

Answer (score 1):

Check out the make_scorer function in sklearn: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html

You may need to code the OoB component yourself, I haven't ever used that metric for scoring before with Sklearn, so I don't know for sure.

Also, consider using random search rather than grid search, it is more practical when dealing with a large hyper parameter space, since it does not need to search the entire dimension of a parameters that have no impact.

Comment: Thanks  for your response Jinglesting . I did try the make scorer - unsuccessfully but will now try to code the OOB metric .

Comment: No problem RDATA, if this answer is correct for you, please don't forget to mark it as so!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry - I know this is on old thread but you can try calling `model.oob_score_` after running your model fit. It should give the OOB accuracy

Comment: How will you do this with GridSearchCV is the question.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm phrasing this correctly.

You can call it as a attribute from the best estimator, i.e.

```
grid_model.best_estimator_.oob_score_
```

so you can't really use `grid_model.oob_score_` because gridsearchcv does not have such an attribute; but you can call the best instance of the random forest model, then call the attribute.